# git submodules - could not get a repository handle for submodule

Tags: git

Git submodule support seems to be very buggy. I tried switching branches in a worktree and now I keep getting this error:

```
fatal: could not get a repository handle for submodule 'the_submodule'
```

What does it mean exactly? What is a repository handle?

Comment: The real question is "Q: What is a git 'submodule'?"  The answer: "Something relatively new, and not necessarily fully supported by all Git vendors (e.g. Gitlab, GitHub/Azure DevOps, etc. etc.) and by all Git commands (e.g. "git worktree", per John de Largentaye's reply [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75933125/421195))".  Look here for more details: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: I wouldn't call them "new" but yes they seem to be very buggy and poorly supported. Simple things like switching branches can get your repo into a [*very* broken state](https://lore.kernel.org/git/7C3FF354-F10E-4822-ACF8-31417B05C099@gmail.com/t/).

Answer (score 15):

The way I got around this was to manually clean up and reinit my problematic submodule:

`git submodule deinit the_submodule`

`git submodule init the_submodule`

`git submodule update the_submodule`

Note that at this time (early 2023), unfortunately, `git worktree` does not play nice with submodules. The manpage for `git-worktree` lists under BUGS:

> Multiple checkout in general is still experimental, **and the support for submodules is incomplete**. It is NOT recommended to make multiple checkouts of a superproject.

(emphasis mine)

Edit: You can also continue git operations even with the broken submodule state by disabling the `submodule.recurse` option (default off), either through `git config` or on a per-command basis with `git -c submodule.recurse=no subcommand ...`

Comment: Yeah this is what I had to do too. I also had to delete some git config file as detailed [here](https://lore.kernel.org/git/7C3FF354-F10E-4822-ACF8-31417B05C099@gmail.com/t/).

Answer (score 0):

I had A similar question arise and needed the clarification that @Timmmm provided with [Lore Kernel Link](https://lore.kernel.org/git/7C3FF354-F10E-4822-ACF8-31417B05C099@gmail.com/t/) regarding the issue twice. As for "what it means", it seems that it means that your local repository has a reference to a legacy name for a submodule, and a new name for a submodule, and when those do not align it can cause a conflict.

As for "what is a repository handle", I **think** that is just the repository location name in the root/.git/modules/ for modules, and it is in use in a repository even if the submodule that it should be in reference to has been deinit'd for a change. The ordering from the [Lore Kernel Link](https://lore.kernel.org/git/7C3FF354-F10E-4822-ACF8-31417B05C099@gmail.com/t/) seems to indicate that it is caused in the way git handles submodules and a path forward to prevent such a user experience is not yet decided.

For anyone happening upon this thread and looking to solve the issue, the suggestion in the link to remove the .git/module/ did work for me as it did the poster. Huge shout out to @Timmmm as I have been on this for about 6 months and only just found this solution. Unlike the suggestion to just use commands without the recurse, I was unable to get into a good state without the extra steps.